# Resizing image in Rails HTML

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an image that looked fine in html, but upon putting it into RubyOnRails as

```
            <figure class="mb-8">
                <%= image_tag "AdobeStock_162479912.jpeg" %>
            </figure>
```

it became now massive. I want it to return to how it looked in basic html. From what I understand this is something I would fix in the css, but I don't where to fix it. What should I do?

Comment: What happened to the image? What was the original HTML code that worked? What is the HTML produced by Rails backend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe one way could be to use [ActiveStorage::Variant](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveStorage/Variant.html). You can then specify the height and width (among other things). Hope this helps. Of course you can also fix it in css by giving it a class and giving that class a fixed/max height/width.